# Editing thousands of XML data

Tags: xml

I am editing a xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Test Store</title>
    <link>http://www.example.com</link>
    <description>An example item from the feed</description>

    <item>
      <id>DB_1</id>
      <title>Diamond Ring</title>
      <description>The Most Beautiful Diamond Ring</description>
      <google_product_category>Accessories</google_product_category>
      <product_type>Rings</product_type>
      <link>http://www.example.com/rings</link>
      <image_link>http://www.example.com/ring.jpg</image_link>
      <condition>new</condition>
      <availability>in stock</availability>
      <discount>10.00%</discount>
      <price>1490.0</price>
      <brand>ABC</brand>
      <item_group_id>GROUP_1</item_group_id>
    </item>

    <item>
      <id>DB_2</id>
      <title>Gold Ring</title>
      <description>Pretty Gold Ring</description>
      <google_product_category>Accessories</google_product_category>
      <product_type>Rings</product_type>
      <link>http://www.example.com/gold-rings</link>
      <image_link>http://www.example.com/gold-ring.jpg</image_link>
      <condition>new</condition>
      <availability>in stock</availability>
      <discount>20.00%</discount>
      <price>500.0</price>
      <brand>ABC</brand>
      <item_group_id>GROUP_2</item_group_id>
   </item>

 </channel>
</rss>
```

You can see that in every "item" element, there is an element "discount". I want to change all element "discount" into "condition", and use "new" as the content. For example:

Before:

```
<discount>10.00%</discount>
```

After:

```
<condition>new</condition>
```

For the renaming of element , I can simply use the find & replace function of any text editor. However, for the element content, since there are thousand of different values (e.g. 10%/20%/23%/etc.), I can't find a way to change all of them into the value "new".

Any idea or tools should I use for such editing purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use a programming language you are familiar with and an XML parsing library in that programming language. Looking at your profile, PHP would be a viable choice - its XML libraries are only as insane as any other, there are many examples out on the  'net and it'll be relatively easy to get results.

Comment: You can also consider [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) the special-purpose language dedicated to manipulate/transform XML files. Most general-purpose languages --Java, PHP, Python, VB-- have libraries to run XSLT 1.0 scripts. And then there are dedicated engines like [Saxon and Xalan](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) that can run 2.0 even 3.0 scripts.

Comment: this is problly <20 lines of code.. see my submission soon

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is just 10+ lines in java with XPath and vtd-xml... here is the code

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
import java.io.*;

public class replaceElements2 {

    public static void main(String[] s) throws VTDException,IOException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\rss.xml", false)){
            System.out.println("parsing error");
            return;
        }
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/rss/channel/item/discount");
        int i=0;
        byte[] ba="<condition>new</condition>".getBytes();
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            xm.remove();
            xm.insertAfterElement(ba);
        }
        xm.output("d:\\xml\\rss_new.xml");
    }
}
```